# How to chain several pipes in an Angular component logic class?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, pipes-filters

In Angular (from version 2) you can use custom pipes to filter a set of data. You can chain those pipes in the template by simply adding them one after the other, like so:

```
<app-orange
    *ngFor="let orange of oranges |
    colorFilter:filteredColor |
    sizeFilter:filteredSize |
    originFilter:filteredOrigin,
    let i = index">
</app-orange>
```

The pipes will filter the data in the template, so you will end up seeing, for example only big dark oranges from Valencia, but in my case, I need to pass the filtered array to my Angular logic code, or the Class, to use it later.

I know that you can use a pipe in a component's logic by simply declaring it in the providers, in the constructor, and using the '.transform' method.

```
export class GuestsListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

oranges = [orange1, orange2, orange3, orange4, orange5];
filteredColor = 'dark';
filteredSize = 'big';
filteredOrigin = 'Valencia';

constructor(
          private colorPipe: ColorFilterPipe,
          private sizePipe: SizeFilterPipe,
          private originPipe: OriginFilterPipe) {}

ngOnInit() {
    const filteredByColor = this.colorPipe.transform(this.guests,this.filteredColor);
    const filteredBySize = this.sizePipe.transform(this.guests, this.filteredSize);
    const filteredByOrigin = this.originPipe.transform(this.oranges, this.filteredOrigin);

}
```

The question is: how can I chain those pipes in the logic? How can I filter at the same time by colour, size and origin without having to manually intersect the three resulting arrays from the individually applied pipes?

```
        const filteredByAll = ???
```

Thanks.